# Eclipse debugger stops at package line

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

How can I tell Eclipse to NOT jump to the first line of every file every time it jumps into a function of an object?

If I chose to step into a member function of an object, Eclipse opens the according file but instead of going straight to that function it always jumps to the first line first.

```
package org.diango.simcalc.pipeline; // <-- This is where the debugger "stops"

import org.apache.commons.lang.NullArgumentException;
// .. imagine more code
```

This is insanely annoying.

Comment: Can you not put a debug breakpoint somewhere below and just hit continue? It should keep going until a bpoint is hit...?

Comment: @ha9u63ar I don't want to set breakpoints everywhere. I just want to `step into (F5)` a function but not visit the `package <whatever>` line. I don't see the point why Eclipse is doing that.

Comment: Have you tried `debugging`  why it is stopping on the package line ??

Comment: @NeerajJain *I am debugging*. I hope you don't suggest me to debug the according Eclipse Plug-in.

Comment: Are you possibly using JRebel? I have the experience that the JRebel plugin causes this behaviour. If you want to fix it, start your launch target withouth the JRebel agent.

Comment: @Jack No. There is no JRebel Plug-in installed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably the same why you sometimes see "file.java:1" in stack traces as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258943/396730): In certain situations Java generates special synthetic methods in your class automatically and these seem to have line number 1.

Eclipse has step filters for the debugger, and this can be used to filter synthetic methods.

In the preferences dialog of Eclipse, go to "Java" -> "Debug" -> "Step Filtering", and enable "Use Step Filters" and "Filter synthetic methods". Make sure to also leave "Step through filters" checked, otherwise you would effectively step over the synthetic method and the actual target method.